# Airtable GET request is not returning any data to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, airtable

I'm using Node with Typescript to make an API call to Airtable for a very basic GET request.

Using Airtable's documentation API function (below), I'm getting all the data I want in my backend console, but when I try to get that data returned via Postman or via my frontend, no data is returned, and the request times out.

I thought it's because I'm not returning the data properly. I've used 'return' in all different places, tried Promises and async/await, but nothing yet has worked.

Here's the Airtable API code in my controller:

```
var Airtable = require('airtable');
require('dotenv').config();
const { API_KEY, BASE } = process.env;
var base = new Airtable({ apiKey: API_KEY }).base(BASE);

const minifyRecord = (record: any) => {
  return {
    id: record.id,
    fields: record.fields,
  };
};

export async function getStudent() {
  const name = 'Jenny';
  await base('Students')
    .select({ filterByFormula: `{Name} = "${name}"` })
    .eachPage(
      function page(records: any, fetchNextPage: any) {
        records.forEach(function (record: any) {
          console.log('Retrieved', minifyRecord(record));
        });
        fetchNextPage();
      },
      function done(err: any) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
      }
    );
}
```

And here is the route which calls that function (you can see all my attempts commented out):

```
import { Application, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { getStudent } from '../controllers/students';

import Responses from '../middlewares';

const response = new Responses();

class Routes {
  public router = (app: Application): any => {
    app.get('/student', getStudent);

    app.get('/student', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      getStudent().then((data: any) => {
        res.send(data);
      });
      // res.send(getStudent);
      // response.ok(200, 'About Us', getStudent);
    });
  };
}
export const route = new Routes().router;
```

The Postman error is 'socket hang up'. I've searched everywhere, but the only thing these Airtable API functions do is simply console the response from Airtable.

Comment: facing same problem, is it resolved? if yes please do share the solution

Comment: not resolved yet, was hoping your comment was a solution, lol